# Set R data.table row order by chaining 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to figure out how to order an R data table based on the chaining of 2 columns.

Here's my sample data.table.

```r
dt <- data.table(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')
         , col1 = c(7521, 0, 7915, 5222, 5703)
         , col2 = c(7907, 5703, 8004, 7521, 5222))

   id col1 col2
1:  A 7521 7907
2:  A    0 5703
3:  A 7915 8004
4:  A 5222 7521
5:  A 5703 5222
```

I need the row order to start with col1 = 0.  The col1 value in row 2 should be equal to the value of col2 in the preceding row, and so on.

Additionally, there generally should always be a matching value that chains the row order.  But if not, it should select the closest value (see rows 4 & 5 below).

The outcome I'm looking for is shown below:

```r
   id col1 col2
1:  A    0 5703
2:  A 5703 5222
3:  A 5222 7521
4:  A 7521 7907
5:  A 7915 8004
```

I think I can write a crazy function to do this.. but I'm wondering if there's an elegant data.table solution.

**EDIT**
I updated the table to include an additional ID with duplicate rows, and a unique source column:

```r
dt <- data.table(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
               , col1 = c(7521, 0, 7915, 5222, 5703, 1644, 1625, 0, 1625, 1625)
               , col2 = c(7907, 5703, 8004, 7521, 5222, 1625, 1625, 1644, 1625, 1505)
               , source = c('c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'w', 'v'))

    id col1 col2 source
 1:  A 7521 7907      c
 2:  A    0 5703      b
 3:  A 7915 8004      a
 4:  A 5222 7521      e
 5:  A 5703 5222      d
 6:  B 1644 1625      y
 7:  B 1625 1625      z
 8:  B    0 1644      x
 9:  B 1625 1625      w
10:  B 1625 1505      v
```

There can be matching values within an ID.  See B, rows 7 & 9 above.  However, there's a unique source for each row where this data comes from.

The desired output would be:

```r
    id col1 col2 source
 1:  A    0 5703      b
 2:  A 5703 5222      d
 3:  A 5222 7521      e
 4:  A 7521 7907      c
 5:  A 7915 8004      a
 6:  B    0 1644      x
 7:  B 1644 1625      y
 8:  B 1625 1625      w
 9:  B 1625 1625      z
10:  B 1625 1625      v
```

In the output, the matching rows, 8 & 9 could be in any order.

Thanks!

Comment: Would ```col2``` have duplicates in an ID? Your example would work as is but if there any more rows, ```col2``` would either be 1625 or a non match.

Comment: Yes.  Not something I thought of.  See edited post for a little more dataset detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach that:

1. Reorders the data which will place the 0 value first.
2. Loops through the rest of the values to return the index of where `col2` matches `col1`.

```
setorder(dt, col1)

neworder = seq_len(nrow(dt))
init = 1L
col1 = dt[['col1']]; col2 = dt[['col2']]

for (i in seq_along(neworder)[-1L]) {
  ind = match(col2[init], col1)
  if (is.na(ind)) break
  neworder[i] = init = ind
}

dt[neworder]

##       id  col1  col2
##   <char> <num> <num>
##1:      A     0  5703
##2:      A  5703  5222
##3:      A  5222  7521
##4:      A  7521  7907
##5:      A  7915  8004
```

If you are doing it with grouping, you can wrap the loop within a `dt[, .I[{...}, by = id]$V1` to return the indices. Or to make it look better, we can make a function.

```
recursive_order = function (x, y) {
  neworder = seq_len(length(x))
  init = 1L

  for (i in neworder[-1L]) {
    ind = match(y[init], x)
    if (is.na(ind)) break

    # Multiple matches which means all the maining matches are the same number
    if (ind == init) { 
      inds = which(x %in% y[init])
      l = length(inds)
      neworder[i:(i + l - 2L)] = inds[-1L]
      break
    }
    neworder[i] = init = ind
  }
  return(neworder)
}

dt <- data.table(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
                 , col1 = c(7521, 0, 7915, 5222, 5703, 1644, 1625, 0, 1625, 1625)
                 , col2 = c(7907, 5703, 8004, 7521, 5222, 1625, 1625, 1644, 1625, 1505)
                 , source = c('c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'w', 'v'))

setorder(dt, col1)
dt[dt[, .I[recursive_order(col1, col2)], by = id]$V1]

       id  col1  col2 source
    <char> <num> <num> <char>
 1:      A     0  5703      b
 2:      A  5703  5222      d
 3:      A  5222  7521      e
 4:      A  7521  7907      c
 5:      A  7915  8004      a
 6:      B     0  1644      x
 7:      B  1644  1625      y
 8:      B  1625  1625      z
 9:      B  1625  1625      w
10:      B  1625  1505      v
```

Comment: This works!  I still need to understand this a little better, but good results.  What would you have to do if the 'id' column has more values?  Let's say it has ids 'b' and 'c' with their own respective values?

Comment: @AlexP please see edit. This matches your expected output of your revised question.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option using `igraph` with `data.table`:

```
#add id in front of cols to distinguishes them as vertices
cols <- paste0("col", 1L:2L)
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) paste0(id, x)), .SDcols=cols]

#permutations of root nodes and leaf nodes
chains <- dt[, CJ(root=setdiff(col1, col2), leaf=setdiff(col2, col1)), id]

#find all paths from root nodes to leaf nodes
#note that igraph requires vertices to be of character type
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dt[, .(col1, col2)])
l <- lapply(unlist(
  apply(chains, 1L, function(x) all_simple_paths(g, x[["root"]], x[["leaf"]])), 
  recursive=FALSE), names)
links <- data.table(g=rep(seq_along(l), lengths(l)), col1=unlist(l))

#look up edges
dt[links, on=.(col1), nomatch=0L]
```

output:

```
    id  col1  col2 source g
 1:  A    A0 A5703      b 1
 2:  A A5703 A5222      d 1
 3:  A A5222 A7521      e 1
 4:  A A7521 A7907      c 1
 5:  A A7915 A8004      a 2
 6:  B    B0 B1644      x 3
 7:  B B1644 B1625      y 3
 8:  B B1625 B1625      z 3
 9:  B B1625 B1625      w 3
10:  B B1625 B1505      v 3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
  , col1 = c(7521, 0, 7915, 5222, 5703, 1644, 1625, 0, 1625, 1625)
  , col2 = c(7907, 5703, 8004, 7521, 5222, 1625, 1625, 1644, 1625, 1505)
  , source = c('c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'w', 'v'))
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I get an error when I do the lapply:  Error in all_simple_paths(g, x[1L], x[2L]) : 
  At paths.c:77 : Invalid starting vertex, Invalid value

Comment: The output for chains is    
root leaf
1:    0 7907
2:    0 8004
3: 7915 7907
4: 7915 8004

Comment: @AlexP, the vertex of the graph has to be of character type. Hence, that is why I use as.character on `col*`

Comment: Ahhhh ok!  I missed the changing of the columns to a character class.  It works!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I should have posted in the original post, but what changes about the code if there are additional IDs?

Comment: Not in front of computer now. I would try pasting the id to both col* to create character vertices and the rest of the code should still work

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately not from what I can see.  B gets ignored in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

A chain sort solution in *base* using `Reduce`.

```
fun <- function(j,k) {
    i[j] <<- FALSE
    r[i][which.min(abs(x$col2[j] - x$col1[i]))]
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dt, dt$id), function(x) {
    assign("x", x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    assign("i", rep(TRUE, nrow(x)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    assign("r", seq_along(i), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    x[Reduce(fun, r[-1], which.min(x$col1), accumulate = TRUE),]
}))
#     id col1 col2 source
#A.2   A    0 5703      b
#A.5   A 5703 5222      d
#A.4   A 5222 7521      e
#A.1   A 7521 7907      c
#A.3   A 7915 8004      a
#B.8   B    0 1644      x
#B.6   B 1644 1625      y
#B.7   B 1625 1625      z
#B.9   B 1625 1625      w
#B.10  B 1625 1505      v
```

Or using a `for` loop:

```
fun <- function(init, from, to) {
  i <- integer(length(to))
  i[1] <- init
  j <- seq_along(to)[-init]
  for(k in seq_along(i)[-1]) {
    x <- which.min(abs(to[i[k-1]] - from[j]))
    i[k] <- j[x]
    j <- j[-x]
  }
  i
}
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dt, dt$id), function(x) {
 x[fun(which.min(x$col1), x$col1, x$col2),]}))
#     id col1 col2 source
#A.2   A    0 5703      b
#A.5   A 5703 5222      d
#A.4   A 5222 7521      e
#A.1   A 7521 7907      c
#A.3   A 7915 8004      a
#B.8   B    0 1644      x
#B.6   B 1644 1625      y
#B.7   B 1625 1625      z
#B.9   B 1625 1625      w
#B.10  B 1625 1505      v
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.frame(id = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
               , col1 = c(7521, 0, 7915, 5222, 5703, 1644, 1625, 0, 1625, 1625)
               , col2 = c(7907, 5703, 8004, 7521, 5222, 1625, 1625, 1644, 1625, 1505)
               , source = c('c', 'b', 'a', 'e', 'd', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'w', 'v'))
```