# How to reorder dataframe rows in based on conditions in more than 1 column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

**The Problem**

I am trying to reorder rows based on the conditions in 2 other columns. Specifically, I have a sequential ID for hundreds of randomly generated sampling transects called "ID_First" and then for each transect there is a corresponding "ID_Next" that represents the next transect that should be sampled. I am trying to reorder the rows such that the sampling transects are in order of execution rather than the original order based on "ID_First"

I know that data frames can be arranged based on one or more columns for numerical variables in either an ascending or descending way and, for factors, in an "ordered" way (e.g., high, medium, low). Is it possible to arrange the order of the rows based on the sequence of ID_first and then ID_Next? I have not been able to figure out how to do this so I have been doing it manually.

**Simplified Reproducible Example**

*Data*

```
# sequential ID for a small number of randomly generated transects 
ID_First <- seq(1,10,1)

# represents the next transect that should be sampled following ID_First
ID_Next <- c(4,5,8,7,10,2,9,6,3,NA)


# make a dataframe
df <- cbind.data.frame(ID_First, ID_Next)

# look at the df
df

>    ID_First ID_Next
> 1         1       4
> 2         2       5
> 3         3       8
> 4         4       7
> 5         5      10
> 6         6       2
> 7         7       9
> 8         8       6
> 9         9       3
> 10       10      NA
```

So, if you start with ID_First equal to 1 and then look at the corresponding ID_Next this would indicate that the next transect to sample is 4. Then you go to ID_First equal to 4 and the corresponding ID_Next to sample next would be 7, and so on. For this example, the order of sampling would progress as follows: 1,4,7,9,3,8,6,2,5,10.

*Ideal Outcome*

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
>    ID_First ID_Next
> 1         1       4
> 4         4       7
> 7         7       9
> 9         9       3
> 3         3       8
> 8         8       6
> 6         6       2
> 2         2       5
> 5         5      10
> 10       10      NA
```

Now the transects are following the order needed for sampling (e.g., 1 to 4, 4 to 7, 7 to 9, 9 to 3, etc. through 10) rather than the ascending ID_First.

*Question*

Is there an easy way to reorder the original data frame using ID_First equal to 1 as the standpoint and then, following the progression of ID_Next to ID_Tirst to ID_Next to arrange the remainder of the transects?

Comment: What happens if/when there's a gap, `ID_Next` points to a value that is not found in `ID_First`?

Comment: Maybe related/duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190256/set-r-data-table-row-order-by-chaining-2-columns/ ?

Comment: Thanks @r2evans I just proofread the question and I did find an error, which has been fixed.  Does the numbers make sense now or is there a specific value that you were referring to?

Comment: I'm not necessarily pointing out problems with your data, I'm wondering about corner-cases and fail-cases. When the assumption that "everything in column 2 will be found in column 1" *fails*, for instance, what is supposed to happen? (I have some very cruel and seemingly not-linear-thinking users, always trying to break my code :-)

Comment: @r2evans  In this case, only the numbers in ID_First are considered as options for  ID_Next. I had originally coded the example ID_Next as sample(2:10, size=9, replace=FALSE), with transect #1 implicitly being the first, but doing it that way made it hard to identify the "endpoint" (transect 10) because the last transect needs to have an NA for ID_Next. The code above could randomly assign 10 at any point in the sequence, rather than at the second to last position, causing early termination of the chain. I could ask a separate question about that?

Comment: Is `ID_Next` `c(4,2,8,7,10,5,9,6,3,NA)` or `c(4,5,8,7,10,2,9,6,3,NA)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` with `match` to find the chain from `ID_First` to `ID_Next`.

```
df[Reduce(function(i,j) match(df$ID_Next[i], df$ID_First)
 , seq_len(nrow(df)), accumulate = TRUE),]
#   ID_First ID_Next
#1         1       4
#4         4       7
#7         7       9
#9         9       3
#3         3       8
#8         8       6
#6         6       2
#2         2       5
#5         5      10
#10       10      NA
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID_First = 1:10, ID_Next = c(4,5,8,7,10,2,9,6,3,NA))
df
#   ID_First ID_Next
#1         1       4
#2         2       5
#3         3       8
#4         4       7
#5         5      10
#6         6       2
#7         7       9
#8         8       6
#9         9       3
#10       10      NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this for your specific example using a while loop and the `match()` function in R. I also used `list.append()` from the `rlist` package.

```
library(rlist)

# sequential ID for a small number of randomly generated transects 
ID_First <- seq(1,10,1)

# represents the next transect that should be sampled following ID_First
ID_Next <- c(4,5,8,7,10,2,9,6,3,NA)


# make a dataframe
df <- cbind.data.frame(ID_First, ID_Next)

#create while loop to define target order
i = 1
order = c(i)

n = 1
while (n < length(df$ID_Next)){
  j = df[df$ID_First == i, 2]
  order = list.append(order, j)
  i = j
  n = n+1
}

#match df order to target order
df2 = df[match(order, df$ID_First),]
```